# How to connect to the deployed smart contract using java

Tags: java, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

smart contract is already deployed, lets say Smart contract name : ABC which has some methods,  in order to call the method in the ABC contract, i need an instance of Contract, if my assumption is right. my question how do i load the smart contract in order to call the methods. all i have is the private key of the smart contract. i have gone through this document https://docs.web3j.io/4.10.0/getting_started/deploy_interact_smart_contracts/, but nothing helps.. not sure how to proceed. any help could be helpfull here

Understanding on how we can load the smart contract which is already deployed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.